# efficient addition of (m, 2), (n, 2) arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, `x` of shape `(m, 2)` and `y` of shape `(n, 2)`. I would like compute the `(m, n, 2)` array where at position `(i, j)` one finds the sum of `x[i]` and `y[j]` at `out[i, j]`. List comprehension works

```py
import numpy

x = numpy.random.rand(13, 2)
y = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)

xy = numpy.array([
    [xx + yy for yy in y]
    for xx in x
])
```

but I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution via `numpy.add.outer` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xy = x[:, None]+y
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpys broadcasting rules to cast the first array to the shape `(13, 1, 2)` and the second to the shape `(1, 5, 2)`:

```
numpy.all(x[:, None, :] + y[None, :, :] == xy)
# True
```

The array is repeated across the dimension where `None` is added (since it has length 1).

Therefore the shape of the output becomes `(13, 5, 2)`.